# Tomcat and IntelliJ in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, sudo, intellij-14

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LST
I'm using IntelliJ 2018.2.1
I installed Tomcat 8.5.32 following this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04.

Everything ok so far, but when I try to add the Tomcat Application Server in IntelliJ, if tomcat is under "/opt/tomcat..." folder I'm not able to add the server, unless I start IntelliJ as SUDO.  The screen just said "The selected directory in not a valid Tomcat home"

If tomcat is outside the opt folder, in "home/tomcat" for example, I'm able to add the server without any problem.

I think that is something with the permision, but even changin the permitions to 777 was not able to add the server.

Any idea???

Answer (score 0):

This link may be able to explain it better than me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership.

You would do: `sudo chown -R $USER: /opt/tomcat`

Also, just personal preference for me. To avoid exactly this I usually keep applications I think will give me this problem somewhere in my home directory.

Also note just moving the files from /opt/tomcat to your home directory probably won't give you permission if you extracted or installed the files in /opt/tomcat as root (but it doesn't sound like you have that problem it just happens to me a lot).